# how to create multiple buttons in kivymd MDDialog box

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

please guys how can I create multiple buttons in MDDialog box in kivymd?
below is the code I tried to use but it only displays one button.
I want it to display multiple buttons according to the number of file format it wants to download.

```
def show_alert_dialog(self, file):
    for i in file:
        self.dialog = MDDialog(text="Discard draft?",
            buttons=[
                MDFlatButton(
                    text=str(i), text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color
                ),
            ],
        )

    self.dialog.open()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop in the `show_alert_dialog()` method creates a new `MDDialog` each time through the loop and each one has a single `Button`. Then when the loop completes, the line:

```
self.dialog.open()
```

opens the last dialog created. The fix is to create the list of buttons in the loop, then create just one dialog with all the buttons, like this:

```
def show_alert_dialog(self, file):
    buttons_list = []
    
    for i in file:
        buttons_list.append(MDFlatButton(text=str(i), text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color))
        
    self.dialog = MDDialog(text="Discard draft?", buttons=buttons_list)

    self.dialog.open()
```